# Does the gender of a game's protagonist affect sales?

Tags: character, sales, demographics

Most protagonists of games are male. I imagine the conventional wisdom is that this is because

1. We live in a patriarchal society, especially when it comes to game development, and
2. The target demographic is predominantly male.

I once heard that for fiction, females are more able to empathise with a male character, than males are with a female character. So the great imbalance in gender in fiction is *not necessarily* due to patriarchy, but that it just makes sense from a financial point of view. I'm not sure if I subscribe to that, but it is interesting.

And there was a time when gaming *was* for super hardcore nerdy males, but now almost everybody has a games machine, and it is not a stigma to like games as it once was, I don't know if it is such a male domain any more.

So leaving aside any question of whether we *should* try to reduce gender stereotypes, 
my question is, does having a female protagonist actually affect sales, in particular, for small indie games? Are there any experiments, statistics or research relating to this question? What is the actual demographic breakdown of gamers these days?

I realise this is an inflammatory subject, so I will stress here that I am not looking for opinions:

### I am looking for hard facts and data.

Comment: I'd actually reword your question. Asking yourself whether a game's protagonist should have a specific gender is the wrong question. Instead, ask yourself whether you can't offer both genders for play. You can only win if you offer both options to everyone (if your budget allows that). As such it would always affect sales, don't get anyone to feel left out. Also, if the story fits, noone will mind the character's gender (take Aquaria as an example).

Comment: Flurry Analytics has a good write-up on their blog about male vs. female and how it affects different genres of games. You should check it out. It's not what you're asking, but it's a good start.

Comment: -1.  Controversial question, not about development, asking for definitive facts where no such facts could possibly exist.

Comment: It's a very good question. A lot of publishers have the unfortunate belief "Female protagonists don't sell." This would be really distressing if it were ever proved true. I worry that there's no solid, incontrivertible data to prove it false though. For instance, games with female leads may open themselves up to more controversies about sexism if certain aspects are handled badly. (In a basic storyline, I'd anticipate no such issues)

Comment: I don't think I would like Metroid series that much if Samus were a man. :G

Comment: @GustavoMaciel Fact is people thought Samus was a Man until later on when someone beat the game with enough points which revealed that Samus Aran was actually a female character. The American booklet of the game explained that Samus was an Android. Eh, I'm not sure if the game would have sold that much if people knew from the get go that Samus is a woman. At least not back in those days.

Comment: Just a note to those who are planning on answering this question, I find it to be an interesting question and while not off topic, it'll be very easy to create subjective answers. **Please ensure your answer contains references and hard data to support your conclusions.**

Comment: @Katana314 Precisely what sort of "solid, incontrovertible data" are you thinking of?  Can you give an example?  I can't think of anything, myself.  You'd have to be comparing two otherwise-identical popular mainstream games marketed to the same group in the same part of the world whose only difference was the gender of the main character.  Right?  Does any such game release exist today?  How would such a game ever come into existence so that we could gather that sort of data in a valid way?

Comment: @TrevorPowell That's basically my point; that there IS NO solid, incontrovertible data. If a game like Mirror's Edge or Portal sells well, that could simply be because their game design and art style were amazing. There's just no good way to compare two high-end games solely on the basis of their protagonist's gender.

Comment: "I am looking for hard facts and data." Well you are not going to find any. Hard data would require isolating the variables and altering the independent one which is the protagonist's gender. This isolation would be impossible there are too many things making a huge impact on sales, game play, hype, the developer’s reputation. If you can’t isolate the variables you have one other option I know of which is to normalize by using a large sample set. Good luck with that. You can’t run a proper experiment to get any meaningful statistical data from.

Comment: So this would be closed an unanswerable and all the people running around yelling about linking to hard data should think about how on earth that data is supposed to be obtained. If they can figure that out they probably should contact Activation or EA get their millions of dollars and drive to MIT to get their honorary PHD.

Comment: Although the question is interesting, I don't think there is really any way you can get a definitive answer. Games vary too much between themselves (as far as narrative, gameplay, and content) to be able to determine if the reason for a games success was due to the gender or ethnicity of the main character. Really the only way to get factual information would be to release a game where you could buy either the female version or male version (you'd have to buy the game twice if you want both) and see how their sales measure up. But no one has done this as it seems like a bad marketing strategy.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question pertaining to the business and marketing side of game development. It would be interesting to see if anyone can come up with any published statistics.

Comment: Thank you to all who have commented. Yes I know it is a controversial question, and that obviously there are no hard data on theoretical game sales. But there surely are scientific studies showing gender preconception, statistics on protagonist gender ratios within genres/markets, statistics on gamer demographics, polls, etc. Real data that can affect business decisions.

Comment: There is a huge leap there between "_we live in a patriarchy society_" and the assumption that "people like to see male heroes in their games".  The fact that most governments and workplaces _are_ currently dominated by male personnel _probably_ has nothing to do with people's interest in seeing male heroes in games.

Comment: @bobobobo I agree with you to a certain extent. However, since the majority of game development companies, are

Comment: @bobobobo I agree with you to a certain extent. However, since there is still an imbalance in the ratio of females in positions of power within the games industry, I would say it does have an affect. Also, I wonder if having a male protagonist is merely a habit more than anything else, left over from a patriarchal society. Things are much more equal now, but perhaps it is more that both genders have an expectation of male characters, rather than truly indicitive of the demographic?

Comment: @DaleyPaley I would agree with you on the 2nd point ("_habit_"), recent human history had males as _Warrior_, which probably led lore and folktales as well. But why do you assume girls want to make games about girls? I think that assumption is flawed. After all plenty of female writers write with male protagonists, and I _don't_ think they do so because they feel "they have to write about a male so the book will sell."

Comment: Thinking about it again, I recall that JK Rowling actually called herself JK to avoid identifying herself as female due to sexism in the book industry.  Indeed she [did it again](http://www.businessinsider.com/jk-rowling-secretly-wrote-a-novel-under-a-mans-name-and-people-thought-it-was-awesome-2013-7) recently.  I really think you're asking if __sexism__ (on the part of the buyer, or on the part of the game creator) plays a role in casting female leads.  But that makes this question OT for this site.

Comment: Good question .. Beside the problem of sexism, I think the gender you should use as a leading character depends on the game type, story, and gameplay style .. The Last of Us feature both a man and a girl

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can **prove** that "having a female protagonist actually affect sales, in particular, for small indie games?"  And I don't think the **sex** of the lead character will deter people from buying games.  Allow me to explain.

The article where an investor said he would not invest in a game with a female lead ["You can't have a female character in games. It has to be a male character, simple as that."](http://penny-arcade.com/report/article/remember-mes-surprising-connection-to-facebook-and-why-its-protagonist-had).  The guy was a **sexist** person with a sexist attitude making great assumptions about buyer attitudes. **Read the comments below the article for a response to that**.

So that's one isolated instance of *somebody* saying something sexist like that.  Of course, they didn't say who it was, whether he was big time or small time, or whether at all he knew the market he was trying to sell to.

So anyway, without a carefully controlled study/social experiment (each *same* game quality, exact same *fun* level, only thing changed: lead male becomes female), it's not really possible to tell *if there is an effect or not*.  But I urge you to think about this rationally and not let sexist attitudes of a couple of people dominate your thinking.  Have **you** ever avoided a game title because the lead was female?  I personally have not.  Have your friends?  **Has anybody you know?**  Why would the market respond negatively to a female lead then?

Now consider the following notable games with female protagonists, leads, or main characters (by no means complete):

- Final Fantasy 6 (Terra).  Terra was the only magic user in a world where magic had all but disappeared (and was forbidden).  The majority of the story **centers** around her, particularly the early parts of the game.
- Portal.  A "maze-shooter" with a female lead character who you see in mirrors at the beginning of the game.
- Mario Bros 2 :  Had princess toadstool, who was arguably the best for beginners to use (since she could float for 5s)
- Warcraft 3 - The Night Elves are a matriarchal society.  2 of the heroes for the race are female including [Maiev](http://www.wowwiki.com/Maiev_Shadowsong) and Tyranda
- Tomb Raider featured Lara Croft.

[There are a lot more games listed here featuring female protagonists](http://www.giantbomb.com/female-protagonists/3015-2287/games/).

So in short, **I don't believe having a female role prevents the game from selling**.  I think how well the game is made, how fun it is, etc, dominate the scales in terms of people liking the game.  The isolated sexist people who say things like "It won't sell because the lead is female" are simply speculating and projecting their sexist views on the entire market.

Comment: +1 This is likely as close as we'll get to a complete answer for this question, unless someone runs a study for exactly this topic.

Comment: +1 Maybe somebody could do an analysis of Nathan Drake vs. Lara Croft. As far as I can tell, Lara Croft is more well know because she was here earlier, but other than that, both game series are popular, profitable and critically acclaimed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Old Opinions

A game recently came out called [Remember Me](http://www.ign.com/games/adrift/ps3-105268). The sad thing about this game is that for most people it flew under the radar. Why? The studio, Dontnod, attempted to get funding and support from multiple investors but couldn't so they weren't able to advertise. Investors did not one to sink money into the game for one major reason, the lead was female. There was a scene where the character's past is explored and she kisses a man, which the investors thought that the male population wouldn't want to see.

Whether or not they were right is not the point, Dontnod couldn't get support due to the lack of faith by the investors, so when it came time to sell their product it flopped due to a rather small and under budget advertising department.

#### The Honest Truth

So then where does this leave us, is making a female lead wrong? Is there a large male gamer population than female? Let's look at the [Sales, Demographic, and Usage Data](http://www.theesa.com/facts/pdfs/ESA_EF_2012.pdf) provided by the Entertainment Software Association. On page 5 it shows that 47% of all gamers are female. What does this mean?

Knowing who all of Dontnod's investors were is impossible but it is a safe assumption that they were male, or just overly cautious about the male consumers. Could the game have done better with more investments, maybe; was it a female lead that caused it to crash, no.

#### Strong Female Leads

There are several examples of female leads in games that did great: Konoko from Bungie's Oni, Lara Croft from Square Enix's Tomb Raider, and Samus Aran from Nintendo's Metroid.

#### Conclusion

I would post more links to show what I mean, but I can't due to the posting limitations, to make a long post simple:

The gaming industry catered towards males for the past twenty years, but as this newest generation began to grow up with technology, the internet, and video games, the gender gap began to close. Sure there are still people out there who will argue against it, but having a female lead shouldn't affect your game much, so long as the character is interesting.

#### Personally

Personal opinion I would never even second guess adding a female to a cast or even making her the lead. If it works with what you are going with than do it, as well as the fact that if more leads are given to female character's than eventually the amount of female leads will be similar to that of males.

Comment: *47% of all gamers are female* - that old chestnut? Your Remember Me anecdote is even more interesting [if you look further](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/188775/You_cant_have_a_female_character_in_games.php%20March%202013). Females may represent half of the *entire gaming population*, but it's a lot less even when you break that apart. [Females represent 74% of casual game sales](http://gigaom.com/2007/10/31/casual-games-worth-225b-but-where-are-they-going/), and there are surveys to the effect of "core" gamers being predominantly male. Casual games tend to have no protagonists.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked how the 47% is divided into, , but that ratio is constantly changing. Slowly, but constant. I have friends who play many core AAA franchises who would be insulted to be considered "less important than males" as far as game development is concerned.

Honestly the argument is a difficult one and attempting to find an answer that pleases everyone is not possible. Don't look at what the information states now, attempt to view where the information will lead you.

Again though, you might be right on the Casual games aspect, didn't look into it too much until now.

Comment: @ISJTrigger Thanks for the interesting info. Small criticism however, I don't think you can use Samus as an example of a successful female protagonist, due to the secrecy of her gender. Also, there is a case to be made that Lara only became famous because she is sexy and acts like a male (at least in the beginning). We all know that *sexy* women will sell games, but not so much for realistic multidimensional ones.

Comment: Can you provide the source for the first paragraph about Remember Me? As well as the other links you mentioned you wanted to post. You have the rep to do so now.

Comment: @DaleyPaley, the problem with saying she "acts male" is really just that only men are portrayed in that situation.  If more females were portrayed as "strong" and "daring" and "adventurous", you wouldn't say she was "acting male", you would say she was a strong character forging her path.  If you want to break down gender barriers, you can't use phrases like "acts male" or "acts female" because that doesn't mean anything.  Is it only that men can have strong traits, or aggressive ones? If so, then the gender gap will never close, and male protagonists will dominate.

Comment: @kurtzbot I take your point. However, I think there is a big difference between, say Lara Croft, and Ellen Ripley. Ripley is a great example of a believably strong female. She shows great inner strength, high intellect, passion, courage, physical strength, and aggression, but never once did I think she was acting like a man. And they didn't need to make her an ugly, butch, short-haired lesbian to do it. But all too often, people make strong females by simply making them 'act like a man'. Lara Croft IS a sexy, big-bosomed woman acting like a man, for the purpose of appealing to young men.

Comment: __"Investors did not one to sink money into the game for one major reason, the lead was female."__  _^citation needed_.  I seriously doubt "investors wouldn't invest because the lead was female."  Valve invested in Portal and the lead was female.  And so was the [team lead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Swift).

Comment: @bobobobo [*"We had some publishers that said, 'Well, we don't want to publish it because that's not going to succeed. You can't have a female character in games. It has to be a male character, simple as that."* - **Jean-Max Morris, creative director**](http://penny-arcade.com/report/article/remember-mes-surprising-connection-to-facebook-and-why-its-protagonist-had)

Comment: So you had one sexist dude saying that stuff. Read the comments below the article for a different perspective.

Comment: @bobobobo: "*So you had one sexist dude saying that stuff.*" Well since that "one sexist dude" is actually *in charge* of deciding what games get funded and what games don't, and the people who make comments are *not* in charge of that, he's a far more useful data point than random people on the Internet. You need to understand the difference between what we would *like* to be true, and what actually *is* true. Valve is Valve; they're privately owned and independently wealthy, so they don't have to fish for money. Not everyone can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Game development is also about creating something that **gives a "feeling" to the user.** You have to set a tone to the game and by setting the tone you can speak to the public outside. Todd Howard has talked about [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7awkYKbKHik) and I find him inspiring.

I personally think that data as you want is not reliable because, even if available, it does not preclude the fact that you might find an idea for a game that will attract female users and male user with the same ratio because the range of devices that support video game has increased and they have a wider reach (see Nintendo Wii and Smartphones).

For me the focus should be about story telling. Any good story if well implemented is potentially successfull and hence any gender "choice" could be potentially valid as you could find an idea that breaks into an unknown market :).

However...  **so far mine is a subjective answer and I wanted to provide you with also some links to published research on this matter so you can have some hard core data and facts to analyze and come up with your own conclusions**:

- [Book "Ethnographies of the Videogame"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0754679780)
- [Article investigating
  gender differences in videogames](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1025631307585#page-2)
- [Another article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0191886905002813) (not
  directly answering the question but here you might find some
  interesting isnights and you could pheraphs search on google for the
  authors name and see if they have done other research on the matter)
- [Another article..](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/cpb.2006.9.308?journalCode=cpb), interesting as it discusses also
  aggressivity. This might be a factor to consider when targeting the
  game (I like to think about Street Fighter, most characters are male
  but some are female and in my experience both male and female user
  play the game with both genders)
- [This looks at the demographic](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/casp.2450050307/abstract;jsessionid=63ADA15708F3767960EB0A23CED67E6D.d01t04?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false)
- [This article instead](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.97.9334) focuses on female teenager gaming, I
  reccomend it

In short:

There is evidence that the demographic of game players are also feemale teenegares (cit [7](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.97.9334)) and if you want to make your player FEEL something you will have to think what YOUR GAME wants to TELL. If it is a story about a FAIRY then the characters will be mostly female, if it is a story about a solider of the 2nd World War then the character could be MALE (but you could have a FEMALE character as supporting character for specific missions - eg. one character is the solider and needs to do certain missions the othe is a nurse and needs to do other missions -save people- and the overall mission score is combined in a co-op multiplayer experience). **Again there is no definite and final answer on this. Fantasy is the beauty and power of video games** (I have no data to prove this :-)).

My conclusion is that is UP TO US to create something groundbreaking that will attract both female and male gender and that ANY research in this field is limited as videogames are increasing their users reach day by day (see what is happening with the Nintendo Wii, families and older people play... it kind of made consoles cool also for eldery people which is an achievement to me and suggests that gaming can be for everyone + see what is happening with smartphone games where you see people playing on smartphones everwhere and with any gender, thing that was not seen with portable consoles).

Answer (score -2):

Although it does, it isn't the most defining trait. What defines characters is how they act, look, talk, move. The gender has an effect of each one of these traits, but to what extent it depends entirely on the designer.

An example of a female character with almost entirely male characteristics is Byonetta. She is basically a female Dante and she is female in order to appeal more to the teenager audiance.

Take Elizabeth from the newest Bioshock for an amazing example for a character who has great depth and is female. Even though she isn't the main character, she is a more developed character than Booker.

Tl;dr: Yes it does, though not alone. When the gender is combined with looks, talk acting it can help appeal to a certain audance therefore increasing sales.

Edit: Let's add another pawn on the table. In order to have a main character, you must have some sort of naritive, if you have some sort of naritive, then it is expected for the player to bond with the character. It would appear that male gamers (which are the majority of single player gamers) have harder time bonding with female characters? Maybe... On the other hand we have Portal, which has huge sucsess and guess what, has a female protagonist. There are a lot of factors. I want to point your attention to two things. One of them is this quote:

> In terms of pure sales numbers, in the first three months of
>   availability, games with only a male hero sold around 25 percent
>   better than games with an optional female hero. Games with exclusively
>   male heroes sold around 75 percent better than games with only female
>   heroes.

And the other is this link:
http://penny-arcade.com/report/article/games-with-female-heroes-dont-sell-because-publishers-dont-support-them

These guys have done an amazing job and I don't want to rip-off their hard work, so just read the article. I think it gives a lot of good points to think on.

Comment: -1 This answer lacks a critical component that the question asks for "I am looking for hard facts and data." You can't say "Yes it does" without backing that up with research. Please edit your answer to include what you're missing.

Comment: I added some more content to it. Check it out now.

Comment: Yes, that article was linked in the other answer. It's a good article, but I don't see how you're validating the first part of your answer by including it.

Comment: Allright, I give up.